# Шахматы с gui на python(без pygame)

Tags: python, gui

Суть моего вопроса такова: есть код шахмат с игрой реализованной в консоли, можно ли сделать gui для этого кода без pygame, tkinter, turtle и т.п.? Буду рад любому дельному совету!

[код(на Яндекс.Диск)](https://yadi.sk/d/H7INpWw6NjIxcQ)

P.S. знаю что с pygame и подобными библиотеками гораздо проще, но мне для проекта нужно без них обойтись(

P.P.S. анимация не нужна, просто 2Д шахматная доска с фигурками, перемещение по принципу: "нажал на фигурку и нажал на место куда передвигаешь её" или "ввёл команду в консоль(по типу: g8 f6 - черный конь с клетки g8 перемещается в клетку f6)" На картинке ниже примерный вид доски и фигурок, который я бы хотел реализовать

[image: пример gui]

Comment: Сделать GUI без библиотеки GUI? Вы хотите в консоли? Или средствами ОС, типа win api?

Comment: С помощью PyQT5, если это возможно.

Comment: Раз PyQt5... делать за вас не буду, поэтому только добавлю свои идеи. Игровая доска это наследник от QWidget, сетку можно сделать через QGridLayout, а ячейки это QLabel (можно их наследники). Клик по ячейкам можно обрабатывать через event-filter либо у наследника QLabel переопределить mousePressEvent и отсылать сигнал, что был клик. Для начала попробуйте создать сетку виджетов. Либо сетку делать через QTableWidget или QTableView + Model, но в них, мне кажется, нужно много переделывать, чтобы выглядело не как шахматы в excel'е

Comment: Ок, спасибо. А насчет фигурок? Их с помощью QPixmap делать?

Comment: Ага и через setPixmap установите их в QLabel и через setAlignment разместите по центру (см https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#alignment-prop)

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрим что из этого выйдет, благодарю